# Set U-boot video resolution?

Tags: ubuntu, arm, u-boot

I recently obtained an Nano-PI [A64 device](https://www.friendlyarm.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=159&search=a64&description=true&category_id=0&sub_category=true) and installed Ubuntu core as [described on the wiki](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_A64#Work_with_Ubuntu-Core). The distro appears to use U-boot but I'm not sure how to set the console video resolution or other boot parameters.

I'm familiar with the boot utils for x86 (grub and the like), but I haven't been able to find much info about how to do this with u-boot. I see [fw_printenv/fw_setenv tools](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/u-boot-tools/fw_setenv.8.en.html) which look like the tools I need, but I haven't been able to find any examples of how to use them (and no /etc/fw_env.config is on the device).

Edit: I should say just running fw_printenv returns an error "Cannot parse config file /etc/fw_env.config: No such file or directory"